# Merge strategy OURS has resulted in fast forward merge jgit

Tags: jgit

I am trying to pull from remote branch to my local. If there are merge conflicts I have set the merge strategy to OURS i.e it should take only my local changes.

But the merge result shows me that "Merge strategy OURS has resulted in fast forward merge" and it is taking the remote changes contradicting to the strategy set(OURS). How can this be resolved in JGit?

```java
  PullCommand pullCommand = git.pull().setRemoteBranchName(file.getProperty("remoteBranchName"));
  System.out.println("repository state"+pullCommand.getRepository().getRepositoryState());
  //Pull the latest changes if the repository is in safe state
  if(RepositoryState.SAFE == pullCommand.getRepository().getRepositoryState()){
    //Merge strategy to be used if there are merge conflicts
    //OURS - to get the local changes, THEIRS- to get remote changes
    if("THEIRS".equalsIgnoreCase(file.getProperty("mergeStrategy"))){
      pullCommand.setStrategy(MergeStrategy.THEIRS);
    }
    else if("OURS".equalsIgnoreCase(file.getProperty("mergeStrategy"))){
      pullCommand.setStrategy(MergeStrategy.OURS);
    }
    //Executes the Pull command
    result = pullCommand.call();
    MergeResult result2 = result.getMergeResult();
```

Comment: Well, this looks like a bug in JGit.Have you tried Have you tried Have you tried setting the fast-forward mode to `--no-ff`? Either by setting the respective configuration setting or by fetching and merging separately with `git.merge().setFastForward( NO_FF )...`.

Comment: Thanks,This strategy is working by fetching and merging separately.